# How to Test a Nested await function in JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

```
const test = async (url, id) => {
  if (!isValidUrl(url)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid URL')
  }
  const storage = new Storage(Indexdb, id);
  const cae = new valueExtract(url);
  const data = await cae.fetch();
  const obj = await new ZIPExtractor(data); // shudder. A constructor should never return a promise
  const zip = await obj.getZip();
  const list = await zip.getList();
  const sI = storage.connection;
  await Promise.all(Object.keys(list).map(async (fileName, index) => {
    const blob = await new FileExtractor(list[fileName]);
    const store = new StoreObject(fileName, 'testData', blob);
    await sI.setItemForce(fileName, store.dataObject);
  }));
  return sI; // or something?
}
```

This is the answer of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968552/converting-promises-code-to-async-await-and-mocking-test-cases) i had asked , I wanted to also know how do we test such nested awaited functions.

unit Test of Normal Fun

```
test('Tes scenario', () => {
  let storage = new StorageAdapter(
    type,
    dbName
  )
  expect(storage.storageName).toBe(dbName)
  expect(storage.storageType).toEqual(type)
  expect(storage.connection).not.toBeNull()
})
```

Comment: Do you know how to unit-test functions that don't use `await`? Please show us how you'd do it

Comment: added it @Bergi

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)?

Comment: I did, but here the problem . is we are interacting with a lot of other ones and i was not able to mock them , properly using a url its works but that is not what it should be ..

Comment: If you are unable to mock your dependencies, then you have moved from a unit test scenario to a functional/integration test one, and you will need to use different tools.  Or it means that you need some substantial refactoring of your code.

Comment: @INFOSYS Not being able to mock your objects doesn't really have anything to do with the code being synchronous or asynchronous, do you think it does? Do you worry about the "nesting"?

Comment: okay @Bergi i will give it one more shot, some hints will be really helpful thanks for all the help